# Need help scraping items from a list with Scrapy using ancestor

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape the details like Contact, Location, Phone and Rate. The html is as below. The list is a dynamic one so sometimes only few of the items like Contact and Location may appear on the page while sometimes all of them can appear. I am thinking I can use the icon tag to get the required text but am unable to find any documentation on this. Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
        <div class="detail-all-label">
        <i class="abc-Contact"></i>
        <div class="detail-all-text"><b>Contact</b>: Ram Bahadur</div>
    </div>
            <div class="detail-all-label">
    <i class="abc-font abc-Location"></i>
    <div class="detail-all-text"><b>Location</b>: Kathmandu</div>
    </div>
<div class="detail-all-label">
    <i class="abc-font abc-Website"></i>
    <div class="detail-all-text"><b>Website</b>: itworkremotely</div>
    </div>
            <div class="detail-all-label">
    <i class="abc-font abc-Phone"></i>
    <div class="detail-all-text"><b>Phone</b>: 3283550121</div>
    </div>
            <div class="detail-all-label">
    <i class="abc-font abc-Rate"></i>
    <div class="detail-all-text"><b>Rate</b>: €700 - 10000</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all of the detail values that have a preceding `b` element inside the `div` with `class="detail-all-text"`:

```
for detail in response.xpath("//div[@class='detail-all-text']/b"):
    name = detail.xpath("text()").extract()[0]
    value = detail.xpath("following-sibling::text()")[0]

    print name, value
```